# To get the given output using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I had been asked an sql query in an interview. I couldn't solve it and still I am unable to. I used joins as was suggested by the interviewer but couldn't get the desired output. The interview got over but I still am curious as to how this problem can be solved. Maybe u guys can help me out

```
Table A
x
x
Table B
x
Output: 
x x
x NULL
```

So there are two tables  table A with 1 column and two rows of same elements and table b of only one element which is same as in table A. Now I have to get the output like shown above.
How to do it?

P.S. The element x is same in all the tables

Is there a simple way to do it without using or mimicing the rownum function .Maybe if we use just join and other function like union or something??

Comment: Which means the two tables don't have a primary key?

Comment: I guess they don't have. that's how the elements are same

Comment: Just now I tried in MS SQL and I selected the row number of the two tables and join them together using the row number as the primary key so they won't be considered as a single record, If you want, I can post the MS SQL since I don't have mySQL in my computer...

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do that with a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT ta,tb FROM table A LEFT JOIN table B ON ta=tb;
```

Comment: no . I already tried it. It gives the output as 1 1
                                                                   1 1 I need a null instead of the last 1

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```
$q = "SELECT table1.*, table2.*
        FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2;

$r = mysqli_query ($db_connnect, $q);


 echo "<table>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) { 

                echo "<tbody>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['table1_elament'] . " </td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['table2_elamant'] . " </td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                echo "</tbody>";   

 }

 echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how this would ever be useful, but here is a solution that works in oracle.

```
select ia.x, ib.x
from (select x, rownum n from a) ia
left outer join (select x, rownum n from b) ib
on ib.n = ia.n
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe1af/2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using only joins but one way to do this is to number the rows in each table and do a left join on the row numbers:

```
select a.x, b.x 
from (
  select @a:=@a+1 'a_rank', a.x 
  from a, (select @a:=0) r
) a 
left join (
  select @b:=@b+1 'b_rank', b.x 
  from b, (select @b:=0) r
) b on a.a_rank = b.b_rank;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6141/1)

Comment: This answer is better than mine, since it works in MySQL without modifications. I'm leaving my answer in place because it does work for oracle.

Comment: wow this query seems to be pretty complex to me. Can you please explain what exactly is going on here?

Comment: It uses variables that are initialized to 0 in the derived tables in the from clauses and then increments them for every row. You can read more about user defined variables here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Comment: owkayy.. seems like I need to do a bit of reading. I will get back to this page in some time

Comment: Sadly MySQL doesn't have any built in row numbering function like most other databases (Oracle has rownum, MSSQL and Postrgesql has the standard row_number() for example), so doing the same thing in MySQL is a bit more complicated.

Comment: instead of that can we use any other in Mysql which would do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    temp.col1,
    temp1.col1
from (select col1,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by col1) as rownum from a)temp
left join (select col1,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by col1) as rownum from b)temp1
on temp.rownum=temp1.rownum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select x.id,y.id
from (select id,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as a from A)x
left join (select id,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as a from B)y
on x.a =y.a
```